# Select nested list

Tags: linq, entity-framework, select

I have three tables in DB like this:

**products**

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | prod1|
+----+------+
```

**values**

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id | value   |  alias  | 
+----+---------+---------+
| 1  |  10 g   |  10m    |
+----+---------+---------+
```

**prdoucts_values**

```
+---------------+---------+
|  product_id   | value_id| 
+---------------+---------+
|      1        |  1      | 
+---------------+---------+
```

How select all products from DB, that have any value from `List<Values.alias>` ?

Comment: Are you using EF, Linq2SQL, or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<decimal> aliases = ...
var query = db.Products.Where(p => p.Values.Any(v => aliases.Contains(v.Alias)));
```

Or (if you don't have navigation properties)

```
var query = from p in db.Products
            join pv in db.ProductsValues on p.ProductId equals v.ProductId
            join v in db.Values on pv.ValueId equals v.ValueId into values    
            where values.Any(v => aliases.Contains(v.Alias))
            select p
```

Comment: Nice, but if Product model not bounded with Values?

Comment: @AlexanderShlinchack see my update with manual join, should work :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF (database first) then the table `prdoucts_values` is not part of the conseptual model.

instead EF givs you a direct path from `Products` to `Values`
Therefore you can write a query that look like this:

```
var lst = new List<Products>();
lst = db.Products.Where(c => c.Values.Any()).ToList();
```